# Mathlink and Parallelization

Tags: parallelization, mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run mathlink external commands in parallel?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-to-run-mathlink-external-commands-in-parallel)

## Abstract

I have a binary file compiled to work with MathLink. I can install the file and run the component functions from within Mathematica without any problems. But, when I try to use Mathematica's inbuilt parallelization with calls to my binary, I get an error that says

```
LinkObject::linkn: Argument LinkObject[/path/to/binary/file.binary,14,8] in
 LinkWrite[LinkObject[/path/to/binary/file.binary,14,8],CallPacket[1,{1,2066455,5.,200000}]]
 has an invalid LinkObject number; the link may be closed.
```

I understand this to mean that MathLink cannot set up links to my binary for some reason? How does one get this to work?

## System Details

I am on a system with 8 cores running x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu.

## Mathematica Code that Produces the Error

Assume `SwitchTimes` is a function defined inside my binary. It takes a number of inputs, but I want to loop over values for one particular input.

```
f[x_] := Module[{A, ma}, 
   A = SwitchTimes[x, RandomInteger[10000000], 5.0, 200000];
   ma = Mean[A];
   ma
   ];

B = ParallelMap[f, Table[i, {i, 1, 100, 2}]];
```

## Code that runs fine

```
f[x_] := Module[{A, ma}, 
   A = SwitchTimes[x, RandomInteger[10000000], 5.0, 200000];
   ma = Mean[A];
   ma
   ];

B = Map[f, Table[i, {i, 1, 100, 2}]];
```

Comment: Maybe try `DistributeDefinitions[SwitchTimes]` before use it?

Comment: Ok, so I add the following to the top of the mathematica notebook:
    `link = Install[myPath<>"file.binary"]; LaunchKernels[]; DistributeDefinitions[SwitchTimes];`

And then use `ParallelMap`. I still get the same errors.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong guess.. I'm not familiar with `MathLink`, maybe wait for others' investigation.

Comment: This may be related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33/877

Comment: I recommend you use LibraryLink instead of MathLink if you are planning to run parallel code.

Comment: @jmlopez actually it seems like a duplicate.,