# How to run an external program in parallel with a Mathematica package?

Tags: packages, parallelization, mathlink-or-wstp, external-calls

Under Mathematica 8 (Linux x84_64) I was able to run an external program in parallel from a Mathematica package. However this procedure breaks down under Mathematica 9.

Within my Mathematica package I created some artificial links for the sub-kernels to be synchronized with the links created by the master kernel. Otherwise the link numbering of the sub-kernels does not coincide with the numbering created by the master kernel. This procedure is different from that suggested by

[How to run mathlink external commands in parallel?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-to-run-mathlink-external-commands-in-parallel)

Here is the relevant code I used in my Mathematica package that did the job successfully under Mathematica 8.

```
Which[SameQ[Global`$ParaMode,"False"] && SameQ[Global`$NotebookMode,"False"],False,
      SameQ[Global`$ParaMode,"False"] && SameQ[Global`$NotebookMode,"True"], False,
      SameQ[Global`$ParaMode,"True"]  && SameQ[Global`$NotebookMode,"False"],kc=$KernelCount;Table[LinkCreate[],{kc-1}],
      SameQ[Global`$ParaMode,"True"]  && SameQ[Global`$NotebookMode,"True"],kc=$KernelCount;Table[LinkCreate[],{kc+6}]
      ];
```

Now let us see what will happen under Mathematica 9. To keep the example small I launch only two sub-kernels.

```
In[1]:= LaunchKernels[2];

In[2]:= $KernelCount

Out[2]= 2
```

After loading my package into the master kernel and sub-kernels I have the following link connections for the master kernel

```
In[50]:= Links[]


Out[50]= {LinkObject[/pfs/data/software/all/mathematica/9.0/Executables/math\

>      -subkernel -noinit -mathlink, 83, 1], 

>    LinkObject[/pfs/data/software/all/mathematica/9.0/Executables/math -subkernel\

>      -noinit -mathlink, 84, 2], LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddma\

>      thlink, 123, 3], LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2g\

>      mp, 124, 4], LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2, 125, 

>     5]}
```

and here the link connections for the two sub-kernels.

```
In[51]:= ParallelEvaluate[Links[]]


Out[51]= {{LinkObject[q63_shm, 3, 1], 

>     LinkObject[34611@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,59020@xxx.xx.xx.xx, 101, 2], 

>     LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink, 102, 3], 

>     LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 103, 4], 

>     LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2, 104, 5]}, 

>    {LinkObject[35c_shm, 3, 1], 
LinkObject[56693@xxx.xx.xx.xx,56906@xxx.xx.xx.xx, 

>      99, 2], LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink, 100, 3], 

>     LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 101, 4], 

>     LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2, 102, 5]}}
```

On a first glance everything seems fine, since the links between the master kernel and its sub-kernels were synchronized as intended.

Now, I want to call a function from my Mathematica package in parallel that makes use of the external program.

```
In[54]:= 
 a2a=ParallelTable[StrongEpsCore3dV6[ExpGame11,EpsStrValues -> t, ViewKernelSol -> True, KernelCoord -> ker, ViewNucleolusSol -
> True, NucleolusCoord -> mnuc, ViewShapleySol -> True, ShapleyCoord -> shv, ShowCore->True, ShowImputationSet -> True], {t, 30, detlow, -(1/40)
}]
```

But to my big surprise, the procedure failed. The strange thing here is that both sub-kernels trying to use the connection build up by the master kernel instead of using their own connections.

```
From KernelObject[2, local]:
LinkObject::linkn: 
   Argument LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 124, 4] in\

>   
    LinkWrite[LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 124, 4],\

>   
     CallPacket[1, {5, 5, {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         {-25369617/<<9>>7, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}]] has an invalid
     LinkObject number; the link may be closed.


From KernelObject[1, local]:
LinkObject::linkn: 
   Argument LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 124, 4] in\

>   
    LinkWrite[LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 124, 4],\

>   
     CallPacket[1, {5, 5, {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         {-25369617/<<9>>7, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}]] has an invalid
     LinkObject number; the link may be closed.
```

My question are now as follows:

How I have to modify the above code so that the sub-kernels are using
   their own connections rather than that of the master kernel?

How can I avoid this unintended behavior?

It might also be helpful to know what changes have been made in the MathLink protocol from Mathematica 8 to 9.

**Update**

In the meantime I made some small progress while starting from scratch without calling any package defined functions. Contrary to my first observation setting the option

> DistributedContexts -> None

might have an effect whenever the function of the external program is called directly. To see this, let us call in a first step the external program directly without setting the option `DistributedContexts -> None`, then we still have the same failure

```
In[17]:= Parallelize[Table[AllVertices[6,5,string1],{2}]]
From KernelObject[2, local]:
LinkObject::linkn: 
   Argument LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 85, 3] in 
    LinkWrite[LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 85, 3], 
     CallPacket[0, {6, 5, {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,
         0, 0,<<11>>, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, -1, -1}}}]] has an invalid LinkObject
     number; the link may be closed.
From KernelObject[1, local]:
LinkObject::linkn: 
   Argument LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 85, 3] in 
    LinkWrite[LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 85, 3], 
     CallPacket[0, {6, 5, {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,
         0, 0,<<11>>, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, -1, -1}}}]] has an invalid LinkObject
     number; the link may be closed.
```

Now, calling the function directly with the option `DistributedContexts -> None` helps in this case, I got the desired result

```
 In[17]:= Parallelize[Table[AllVertices[6,5,string1],{2}],DistributedContexts -> None]
Out[17]= {{{{{1, 1,  0,  0,  0}, {1,  0, 1,  0,  0}, {1,  0,  0, 1,  0}, 

>       {1,  0,  0,  0, 1}}, {}}, {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, 

>      {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}}}, {{{{1, 1,  0,  0,  0}, {1,  0, 1,  0,  0}, 

>       {1,  0,  0, 1,  0}, {1,  0,  0,  0, 1}}, {}}, 

>     {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}}}}
```

Nevertheless, when I try to invoke the above package function again with the option `DistributedContexts -> None` to call indirectly the external program, then I still get the same failure. Nothing has improved.

It seems that the option `DistributedContexts -> None` must be put in the right place in order to have an effect. But how I have to do that?

**Update 2**

To simulate a package function call of the external program, I defined ceteris paribus the following indirect function call

```
 In[15]:= callVert[m_Integer,d_Integer,a_String]:=AllVertices[m,d,string1];
 In[16]:= DistributeDefinitions[callVert]
 Out[16]= {callVert}
```

To observe that the function is well defined, we call this function first by the master kernel and obtain

```
 In[19]:= callVert[6,5,string1]
 Out[19]= {{{{1, 1,  0,  0,  0}, {1,  0, 1,  0,  0}, {1,  0,  0, 1,  0}, 

>      {1,  0,  0,  0, 1}}, {}}, {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, 

>     {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}}}
```

which coincides with the above result.

However, calling now the above indirect function using `Parallelize` with option `DistributedContexts :> None`, we attain still the same failure

```
Parallelize[Table[callVert[6,5,string1],{2}],DistributedContexts :> None]
From KernelObject[2, local]:
LinkObject::linkn: 
   Argument LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 88, 3] in 
    LinkWrite[LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 88, 3], 
     CallPacket[0, {6, 5, {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,
         0, 0,<<11>>, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, -1, -1}}}]] has an invalid LinkObject
     number; the link may be closed.
From KernelObject[1, local]:
LinkObject::linkn: 
   Argument LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 88, 3] in 
    LinkWrite[LinkObject[/pfs/data/home/kit/xxxx/xxxx/bin64/cddmathlink2gmp, 88, 3], 
     CallPacket[0, {6, 5, {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,
         0, 0,<<11>>, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, -1, -1}}}]] has an invalid LinkObject
     number; the link may be closed.

Out[21]= {$Failed, $Failed}
```

I even tried

```
In[17]:= $DistributedContexts = None;
In[18]:= Map[SetOptions[#,DistributedContexts :> None]&, {Parallelize}];
In[19]:= Options[Parallelize]
Out[19]= {Method -> Automatic, DistributedContexts :> None}
```

without any effect.

What's going on here? Why is it not possible to apply the option `DistributedContexts :> None` in an indirect function call for an external program?

Comment: Can you try `ParallelEvaluate`/`ParallelTable` with option `DistributedContexts -> None`? I find that the automatic distribution of definitions usually causes more problems than it saves and you may have encountered an issue with it here. As for the MathLink protocol: no (externally observable) changes were made between 8 and 9. We are still on `MLINTERFACE` version 3.

Comment: I tried your suggestions with option DistributedContexts -> None. However, without any effect. Still the same failure.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem! The solution is quite simple. It is not allowed 
 to distribute the definition of an indirect function to the sub-kernels. Thus, if we do not use ceteris paribus

```
In[17]:= (* DistributeDefinitions[callVert] *)
```

then setting the option `DistributedContexts :> None` by

```
In[18]:= Map[SetOptions[#,DistributedContexts :> None]&, {Parallelize}];
 In[19]:= Options[Parallelize]
 Out[19]= {Method -> Automatic, DistributedContexts :> None}
```

we can successfully call the external program by the indirect function `callVert`, as we can see next

```
In[25]:= Parallelize[Table[callVert[6,5,string1],{2}]]
Out[25]= {{{{{1, 1,  0,  0,  0}, {1,  0, 1,  0,  0}, {1,  0,  0, 1,  0}, 

>       {1,  0,  0,  0, 1}}, {}}, {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, 

>      {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}}}, {{{{1, 1,  0,  0,  0}, {1,  0, 1,  0,  0}, 

>       {1,  0,  0, 1,  0}, {1,  0,  0,  0, 1}}, {}}, 

>     {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}}}}
```

Referred to my Mathematica package, this means that I made the mistake to distribute the package contents besides with `ParallelNeeds` also with `DistributeDefinitions` to all sub-kernels to be sure that the complete package contents is distributed to the sub-kernels. In the past, I noticed that the function definitions were not distributed properly. This fixed the problem  under Mathematica 8, but caused a break down of the external parallel computation under Mathematica 9.

Thus, if I make now a proper call of my Mathematica function and launching 12 sub-kernels

```
 In[55]:= AbsoluteTiming[a2a=ParallelTable[StrongEpsCore3dV6[ExpGame11,EpsStrValues -> t, ViewKernelSol -> True, KernelCoord -> ker, ViewNucleolusSol -> True, NucleolusCoord -> mnuc, ViewShapleySol -> True, ShapleyCoord -> shv, ShowCore->True, ShowImputationSet -> True], {t, 30, detlow, -(1/40)},DistributedContexts -> None]]

Out[55]= {19.135421, {-Graphics3D-, -Graphics3D-, -Graphics3D-, ... }
```

then the function generates 2158 graphics in parallel in about 19 seconds rather than in 80 seconds.

```
 In[57]:= Length[a2a]
 Out[57]= 2158
```

We are done!

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrR for his useful comment.

Comment: Hi Holger, if you solve your own problem, you can post that as an answer instead of adding it to the question and posting a pointer to it. For now, I've moved the relevant content from your question to this post.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but this was not so clear from the menu. I will keep it in mind.