# Any packages for vertex enumeration on Mathematica?

Tags: packages, polyhedra

My work requires me to enumerate all vertices of a polytope defined by linear inequalities from time to time. And I'm mainly working with _Mathematica 9.0 on *Mac OS X 10.9*. So I wonder are there any packages in *Mathematica* which can be used for **vertex enumeration**.

I know a very old *Mathematica* package `VertexEnum.m` which can be found from [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/440/).

I have tested the package and it still works on *Mathematica 9.0* with a minor modification. The main drawback of this package is its efficiency. It's much slower than calling `MPT3` toolbox in *MATLAB* via *MATLink* package on *Mathematica*. As far as I know, they share the same vertex enumeration algorithm, the *Double Description Method of Motzkin et al.*.

Currently I have several questions in mind. I tried to *Google* them but I failed to get answers. Any  comments or suggestions are most welcome.

1. Are there any packages in *Mathematica* doing vertex enumeration on _Mathematica?
2. Is there a latest `VertexEnum.m` package whose efficiency is increased?
3. Is there a *Mathematica* interface to `cddlib` which works with *Mathematica 9.0* on *Mac OS X 10.9*?

As I don't have enough reputations to post too many links. Interested readers can go to comments for more information.

Comment: The C-library `cddlib` is a `C` implementation of the `Double Description Method of Motzkin et al.` which is widely used for vertex enumeration. One can find the homepage of `cddlib` [here](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/cdd_home/). The author of `cddlib` happens to be the same person with the author of `VertexEnum.m` package, [Prof. Komei Fukuda](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/). Maybe he wants to make the algorithm compatible with more platform, so he stops updating `VertexEnum.m` and concentrates on `cddlib`.

Comment: In his homepage, he provides an `Mathematica` [interface](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~fukuda/download/cdd/cddlibml_binary/) to `cddlib`. However, it's platform dependent and too old to work with current version of `Mathematica`. I tried to recompile the `Mathematica` interface to `cddlib`, but I got stuck at the very beginning. Actually, I have another question on recompiling `Mathematica` interface to `cddlib`. Interested readers can find the question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59128/cannot-install-prebuilt-cddmathlink-on-mathematica).

Comment: Under Linux I had no problems to compile the cddmathlink,cddmathlink2 and cddmathlink2gmp libraries for cddlib-094g using the following complier flags MLFLAGS =  -lML64i4 -lpthread -lrt -luuid -ldl for Mathematica 10. They work perfectly. Write me an e-mail if I should send you the Makefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using cddlib you can use the nicely packaged version in [polymake](http://polymake.org/doku.php), which certainly installs without problems on OS X, and you can just call by an external function call from Mathematica (no mathlink interface necessary). polymake has a lot of other functionality too.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. `Polymake` satisfies all my requirements. Besides, I found another open-source software called `Sage` which is incredibly powerful. With all the respect, let us just leave this question open for now and see where it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I didn't realize the usage of Polymake until recently. But I have difficulty in calling external functions  from Mathematica. Hence a new [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111835/calling-polymake-functions-from-mathematica?lq=1) is created. I referred to  some tutorials on external calls. But I still have no idea on how to call functions in Polymake. So can you share your ideas on calling functions in Polymake from Mathematica?

Answer (score 3):

Glancing through your last posts, it seems to me that you are still looking for a library under Mathematica that enumerates all vertices of a polytope. But you are very close to the answer. It is the C-implementation of the cddlib library for Mathematica by Komei Fukuda. This also works fine under Mathematica. There, the library is called Cddmathlink and you have to compile it by yourself. Under Linux (SLES11) I have to impose the following compiler flags

> MLFLAGS = -lML64i4 -lpthread -lrt -luuid -ldl

to successfully compile cddmathlink, cddmathlink2gmp and cddmathlink2 under Mathematica 10.x (see also my comment from Dec. 7 2014 above). However, you have to download cddlib-094f.tar.gz and cddlib-094h.tar.gz. The former you use to copy the directories src-mathlink and src-mathlink2 in the root directory of cddlib-094h. Edit the Makefiles in src-mathlink and src-mathlink2 folders, and then call the commands "./configure && make all" in the root directory of cddlib-094h. After the compilation has terminated successful, you need to change in src-mathlink and src-mathlink2 to call again the make command.

I use these libraries for years with success for my Mathematica package TuGames (download tugames-v2.3.7z), that can be found here

[TuGames Version 2.3](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5709/)

To have an idea how I use these libraries, I recommend to have a look on the third answer of the following question

[How to plot a core of a cooperative game.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49271/how-to-plot-a-coalition-game)

or for doing the same even in parallel have a look at

[How to run an external program in parallel with a Mathematica package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25561/how-to-run-an-external-program-in-parallel-with-a-mathematica-package)

After you have compiled the libraries successfully, copy them in a bin-directory. Then call from a Mathematica session the following commands to open the links to Mathematica.

```
SetDirectory["/where/cddmathlink/is/located/bin64"]

cddml=Install["./cddmathlink"];
cddmlgmp = Install["./cddmathlink2gmp"];
cddml2=Install["./cddmathlink2"];
```

Alternatively, glance through the Mathematica file TuGames.m to get more ideas how to build up or close links with this library. You will also find in the README files some further instructions. If you need my Makefiles as templates, let it me know. I hope this helps.

**Update 29.05.2016**

Due to a private conversation, I saw some need to update my answer in order to overcome possible pitfalls which might occur during a compilation of the Cddmathlink binaries. My remarks are related to a Linux OS, but I am sure that with some small modification those are also applicable for Mac and Windows users.

First of all, do not use the mathlink.h header file that ships with the cddlib-094f.tar.gz archive file. This version is too old for Mathematica 8.x or higher. Instead of that use the mathlink.h and libML library that ship with your Mathematica version, and that should be located relatively to the Mathematica root directory, for instance, at

> ./10.3/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions

We see that we have to use the 64-bit version of the libML library. Do not try to link it against the 32-bit version. This will not work.

Furthermore, if the compilation of the libcdd libraries have been successfully terminated, the libcdd.a can be found relatively to the root directory cddlib-094h at

> ./lib-src/.libs/libcdd.a

Now, one has to adjust the following lines in the Makefile located in the src-mathlink directory to

```
ml : cddmathlink

     cddmathlink : cddmathlinktm.o cddmathlink.o cddmlio.o

        ${CC} -O3 -I${MLINCDIR} cddmlio.o cddmathlinktm.o cddmathlink.o -L${MLLIBDIR} ${MLFLAGS} $(LFLAGS) ../lib-src/.libs/libcdd.a -o cddmathlink
```

Similar for the src-mathlink2 directory, we have to adjust the Makefile to

```
ml : cddmathlink2 cddmathlink2gmp

    cddmathlink2 : cddmathlinktm.o cddmathlink.o cddmlio.o
         ${CC} $(LIFLAGS) -I${MLINCDIR} cddmlio.o cddmathlinktm.o cddmathlink.o -L${MLLIBDIR} ${MLFLAGS} ../lib-src/.libs/libcdd.a -o cddmathlink2

    cddmathlink2gmp : cddmathlinktm.o cddmathlink_gmp.o cddmlio_gmp.o
         ${CC} $(LIFLAGS) -I${MLINCDIR} cddmlio_gmp.o cddmathlinktm.o cddmathlink_gmp.o -L${MLLIBDIR} ${MLFLAGS} -lgmp ../lib-src-gmp/.libs/libcddgmp.a -o cddmathlink2gmp
```

If you still get some errors like "undefined reference to" invoke first a "make clean" in the folders above, and then rebuild it again. If the "undefined reference to" errors are still present, then change in the Makefiles the compiler to

```
#CC=/usr/local/bin/mcc
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
```

Execute again a "make clean", and then again a "make all". This should build clean and fine Cddmathlink binaries.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! But I'm afraid that I cannot adopt your solution, as I just accepted the solution of Igor Rivin a few days ago even though I still didn't figure out how to call *Polymake* functions from *Mathematica* directly. The good news is that I have succeeded in compiling the *mathlink* interface to *cddlib* and making it work properly a few months later after this question. But I really appreciate your cues on how to compile it years ago and your solution provided hours ago.